# react-native navigation v3 tabIcons not displaying

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am implementing authentication flow with react-navigation v3, I want to have icons and label should display on the tab Bar.  After implementation, the icons on the tab bar do not display only the label does.

```
//Assigninig of TabBar Icon and Config..
const getTabBarIcon = (navigation, focused, tintColor) => {
  const { routeName } = navigation.state;

  let iconName;
  if (routeName === "Explore") {
    iconName = `ios-heart${focused ? "" : "-empty"}`;
  } else if (routeName === "Inbox") {
    iconName = `ios-mail${focused ? "" : "-open"}`;
  }

  return <Icon name={iconName} size={24} color={tintColor} />;
};

//Creating a BottomTab
const AppTab = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Explore: ExploreScreen,
    Inbox: InboxScreen

  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
        getTabBarIcon(navigation, focused, tintColor);
      }
    })
  },
  {
    tabBarOptions: {
      activiTintColor: "tomato",
      inactiveTintColor: "gray"
    }
  }
);

//Inserting BottomTab Navigation into StackNavigator
const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  AppStack: AppTab
});

  //Compiling all Screens into SwitchNavigator
const NavigationConfig = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    SplashScreen: SplashScreen,
    App: AppStackNavigator,
    Auth: AuthStack
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "App"
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning a component to tabBarIcon prop, so just add the return, that will fix your Icon render.

```
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
        return getTabBarIcon(navigation, focused, tintColor);
      }
    })   
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

const AppTab = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Explore: ExploreScreen,
    Inbox: InboxScreen

  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
         const { routeName } = navigation.state;
        let iconName;
        if (routeName === "Explore") {
          iconName = `ios-heart${focused ? "" : "-empty"}`;
        } else if (routeName === "Inbox") {
          iconName = `ios-mail${focused ? "" : "-open"}`;
        }

         return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={24} color={tintColor} />;
      },
      }
    })
  },
  {
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: "tomato",
      inactiveTintColor: "gray"
    }
  }
);
```

You have typo in activeTintColor
For more read [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/tab-based-navigation.html)

Blockquote